# How to improve the performance of mongodb map/reduce

Tags: performance, mongodb, mapreduce

my mongodb cluster use 3 shards with 70 million records.

hardware: 16g memory.

And I want to use below map/reduce progress to do some count.

```
db.runCommand({
    mapReduce: 'orders',
    map: function(){
        var key = { 'name': this.Receiver_name, 'mobile': this.Receiver_mobile };
        var values = { 'count': 1, 'dates': [ this.Receiver_date ] };
        emit(key, values);
    },
    reduce: function(key, values){
        var result = { count: 0, dates: 0 };
        var dates = [];      
        values.forEach(function(value){
            result.count += value.count;
            dates = dates.concat(value.dates);
        });
        result.dates = new Date(Math.min.apply(Math, dates));
        return result;
    },
    sort: { Receiver_name: 1, Receiver_mobile: 1 }, //do index
    out:  { replace: 'localtest' }
})
```

I reference some advices with [How to speed up MongoDB Map Reduce by 20x](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/54709368492/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-map-reduce-by-20x) without using multithread and multi db. Due to mongodb test multithread mising on 2.6.11, I cannot use ScopedThread() function.

So the result still run about

[image: db.currentOp()]

---

below is current operation log: S1 is finished, notice S3 only 2% in map phase.

```
{
    "inprog" : [ 
        {
            "opid" : "s3:99457482",
            "active" : true,
            "secs_running" : 1644,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(1644096961),
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "express.orders",
            "query" : {
                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
            },
            "client_s" : "222.31.79.193:36487",
            "desc" : "conn41",
            "threadId" : "0x7fc4ff361700",
            "connectionId" : 41,
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "msg" : "m/r: (1/3) emit phase M/R: (1/3) Emit Progress: 740369/29745378 2%",
            "progress" : {
                "done" : 740369,
                "total" : 29745378
            },
            "numYields" : 213942,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(299591221),
                    "w" : NumberLong(1368691)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(708109),
                    "w" : NumberLong(91251)
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "opid" : "s2:158299848",
            "active" : true,
            "secs_running" : 1644,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(1644123918),
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "express.orders",
            "query" : {
                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
            },
            "client_s" : "222.31.79.193:48366",
            "desc" : "conn2332",
            "threadId" : "0x7f850d9a6700",
            "connectionId" : 2332,
            "locks" : {
                "^" : "r",
                "^express" : "R"
            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "msg" : "m/r: (1/3) emit phase M/R: (1/3) Emit Progress: 28830696/30690385 93%",
            "progress" : {
                "done" : 28830696,
                "total" : 30690385
            },
            "numYields" : 288816,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2522717442),
                    "w" : NumberLong(56346161)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(750081),
                    "w" : NumberLong(8547462)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Comment: Do the shards have the same amount of memory? S2 seems to be yielding almost as much in 2% as S3 in 93%.

Comment: S1 is 54g(so he finished), S2 and S3 is 16g.

Comment: Either you should upgrade memory of S2 and S3 or compensate with faster SSD.  SSDs will improve your query speed by many folds.

Comment: Why are you using mapReduce? Have you tried `.aggregate()`? It's quite simple `{ "$group": { "_id": { "name": "$Receiver_name", "mobile": "$Receiver_mobile" }, "count": { "$sum": 1 } "dates": { "$min": "$Receiver_date" } }}`. Also use an `$out` if needed.

Comment: Yeah, I used Aggregation Framework(AF). But when occur 16mb result document size error, I chioce mapReduce(MR). Now, I know AF also have $out operator. Recently, I compare two method. AF maybe more faster 10~20%. Is anything incorrect that AF is performancing than MR?